# Deeplinking doesn't pass the URL from browser

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I have a react native app which has a root `App.js` component. In there I have code like the following:

```
import { Linking, ... } from 'react-native';
// other imports

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      console.log('URL:', url);
    });
  }

  render() {
    // render the application...
  }
}
```

I have my manifest set up in such a way as to catch this URL:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="clamberdev.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I run this app from Android Studio with the following Launch options:

[image: Android launch options]

it works as expected and I can see the URL logged to the console.

When I open Firefox or Chrome on the phone and I try to visit `https://clamberdev.page.link/gym-visits-new` it will open my application but the value logged to the console will be `null` (or undefined, can't remember). This happens regardless of whether the app is closed or simply backgrounded.

How do I get the URL logged to the console when deeplinking from a browser?

I've tried using `launchMode="singleTask"` and that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If yes, how did you solved it? I'm facing exactly similar issue on RN v0.59.8